# How to test the broadcast made to a channel from different channel or controller?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a driver channel which broadcasts their location to a vendor channel.

```
defmodule MyApp.DriverChannel do
    #...

    def handle_in("transmit", payload, socket) do
      MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast! "vendors:lobby", "track", payload
      {:noreply, socket}
    end
end

defmodule MyApp.DriverChannelTest do

  #....

  test "location broadcasts to vendors:lobby", %{socket: socket} do
    push socket, "transmit", %{"hello" => "all"}
    assert_broadcast "track", %{"hello" => "all"}
    # Want something like this
    # assert_broadcast "vendors:lobby", "track", %{"hello" => "all"}
  end

end
```

This assertion would fail, as it only checks the broadcast from `DriverChannel`, how to assert the broadcast made to `VendorChannel`, I looked through the source code, it seems like there is no option to pass a `channel_name` to `assert_broadcast` macro.

[ Another note] I also have broadcast made from controllers, if I know answer to this, I could also assert those broadcasts too! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`assert_broadcast` is only for the subscribed topic, but you can subscribe directly via MyApp.Endpoint.subscribe/2 and `assert_receive`:

```
test "location broadcasts to vendors:lobby", %{socket: socket} do
  MyApp.Endpoint.subscribe(self, "vendors:lobby")
  push socket, "transmit", %{"hello" => "all"}
  assert_broadcast "track", %{"hello" => "all"}
  assert_receive %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{
    topic: "vendors:lobby",
    event: "track",
    payload: %{"hello" => "all"}}
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in the channel tests :) I tried doing it in a controller test, but it throws an error "No message matching". I have a controller action `track` with `MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast! "vendors:lobby", "track", %{ "hello" => "all" }` and could not use `assert_receive` on this in my controller tests :(

Comment: What does the failing `assert_receive` error say is currently in your mailbox? It will either say your mailbox is empty or it will show the current contents of the messages in the mailbox. It's possible you are getting the message but not matching on it properly. Or your tests is exposing a bug in your control implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The new version you need `self`

- to subscribe:  `MyApp.Endpoint.subscribe("vendors:lobby")`
- to unsubscribe: `MyApp.Endpoint.unsubscribe("vendors:lobby")`

if you do not 'unsubscribe' you will have a warning:

```
[warning] Passing a Pid to Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe is deprecated. Only the calling process may subscribe to topics
```

new code:

```
test "location broadcasts to vendors:lobby", %{socket: socket} do
  MyApp.Endpoint.subscribe("vendors:lobby")
  push socket, "transmit", %{"hello" => "all"}
  assert_broadcast "track", %{"hello" => "all"}
  assert_receive %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{
    topic: "vendors:lobby",
    event: "track",
    payload: %{"hello" => "all"}
  MyApp.Endpoint.unsubscribe("vendors:lobby")
end
```